# Why we uses nonpublic inheritance when we need to share a common virtual base class or override the construction of a virtual base class?

Tags: c++, inheritance

Herb Sutter's book exceptional C++ item24 explains several cases when we uses nonpublic inheritance. Nonpublic inheritance means public or protected inheritance of class.

I understand other cases but I'm not clear the case 4 below.

> why use nonpublic inheritance? Here are several reasons, in rough order from most to least common.
>
> case 1 blah...
>
> case 2 blah...
>
> case 3 blah...
>
> case 4 We need to share a common virtual base class or override the construction of a virtual base class. The first part applies if the using class has to inherit from one of the same virtual bases as the used class. If it does not, the second part may still apply. The most-derived class is responsible for initializing all virtual base classes, so if we need to use a different constructor or different constructor parameters for a virtual base, then we must inherit.

What does this sentence mean?
Could someone give me some example code for this ?

Comment: virtual and public are independent of each other, so not a conflict. What part of the text causes you problem?

Comment: My question is why we have to use not public inheritance but private inheritance for this case ?

Comment: I don't know either. An example from the standard library is [basic_iostream](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_iostream) which inherits from both `basic_istream` and `basic_ostream`, each of which have a virtual base class. All using public inheritance.

Comment: Quite frankly the text is quite difficult to read. I think a couple of examples with code would have been better. Personally I avoid to do too complicated code, it usually just blows up in my face down the line.

Comment: I added more quotes so that you can understand easily. There is only text and no sample code in this book for this sentence, that's why I am also confused.